# Angular Removed # tags in urls. But not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just removed # tag from my url of angular single page app.

I did like.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

And It worked fine.

My problem is when I directly enter any url to the browser it showing a 404 error. And its working fine when I traverse throughout the app through links.

```
Eg: www.example.com/search  
    www.example.com/search_result
    www.example.com/project_detail?pid=19
```

All these url's are working fine. But when I directly enter any of the above url's into my browser it showing a 404 error.

Please any thoughts on it. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to configure your sever.

Comment: Please let me know what sort of configuration. Its a single page app.

Answer (score 0):

Well i had a similar problem. The server side implementation included Spring in my case.

**Routing on client side ensures that all the url changes are resolved on the client side. However, When you directly enter any such url in the browser, the browser actually goes to the server for retrieving a web page corresponding to the url.**

Now in your case, since these are VIRTUAL urls, that are meaningful on the client side, the server throws 404.

> You can capture page not found exception at your server side
>   implementation, and redirect to the default page [route] in your app.
>
> In Spring, we do have handlers for page not found exceptions, so i
>   guess they'll be available for your server side implementation too.

Comment: Thanks. But before removing the # tags it was working in the other way.

Answer (score 0):

When using the History API you are saying:

"Here is a new URL. The other JavaScript I have just run has transformed the page into the page you would have got by visiting that URL."

**This requires that you write server side code that will build the page *in that state* for the other URLs.** This isn't a trivial thing to do and will usually require a significant amount of work.

However, in exchange for that work you get **robustness** and **performance**. When one of those URLs is visited it will:

- work even if the JS fails for any reason (such as a dropped network connection or a client (such as a search engine) that doesn't support JS)
- load faster than loading the homepage and then transforming it with JS

Comment: Before removing # tags It was working as expected.  I been building a single page app. So will it be feasible to configure in server for this particular problem.

Comment: @Explore-X — Before removing the # you were loading the homepage and depending on JS to run to transform it. It isn't a question of "configuring" the server, you need to write server side code to do the same job as JS. That is possible. Whether or not it is feasible depends on the specifics of the application (which will determine how much work needs to be done) and your resources (which determine how much work you are able to do).

Answer (score -1):

You need to use rewrite rules. Angular is an single page app, so all your request should go to the same file(index.html). You could do this by creating an `.htaccess`.

Assuming your main page is index.html.

Something like this (not tested):

```
RewriteRule ^(.)*$ / [L,QSA]
```

L flag means that if the rule matches, don't execute the next RewriteRule.

QSA means that the URL query parameters are also passed with the rewrited url.

More info about htaccess: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: That makes using html5Mode pointless. You end up with a bunch of duplicate content (every URL is the homepage). If you're going to do that then you might as well stick with hashbangs (which are awful, but (arguably) less awful than this and less work).

Comment: That's not true. Angular router, or UI-router initialises the correct page by the given URL. If you press F5 on your page, the correct page will be loaded.
I also recomment using the '#' for the page navigation. Like I said, Angular is an single page app.

Comment: That's my point. You need the Angular JS to run for the page to load. The point of the history API is to allow a server side fallback so that you don't need JS support.

Comment: You can't make an (interactive)Angular app without javascript. It would not make sense to develop an javascript application if some of your users don't have javascript enabled. Your solution applies only if you use Angular to show simple content on your website without user interaction. Then it's possible to have an static fallback from the server.

Comment: You can't make an angular app without JavaScript. You can make an angular app that doesn't **depend** on JavaScript. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript . JavaScript is an excellent tool for providing more responsive pages and nicer UIs. You can build those on top of plain HTML + server side ones so it continues to work for everyone. You might decide that isn't cost effective, but then there isn't much point in using html5mode over hashbangs since html5mode is there to give the benefits of hashbangs but with URLs that work without JS.